# AngularJS polling a $resource on an $interval doesn't automagically resolve the promise returned from $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource, angular-promise

So, the important bits:
When I bind a $scope variable in my controller directly to a $resource, angular's automatic promise resolution takes over and my view gets updated as soon as data comes back from the service.  However, I need to poll the server for updates on an interval. Attempting to bind to the promise returned from the $interval call is not triggering angular's automatic promise resolution and I do not know if there is something that can be done to get this $interval working against a $resource.

Angular client, ASP.NET WebApi serving JSON, Angular $resource sitting over WebApi.  Inside my angular controller, if I bind a $scoped variable to my $resource promises directly, I get results; however, I need my $resources to update on an $interval and I am having problems introducing the interval.

The working, "needs manual refreshing" code (the relevant part, at least)

```
'use strict';
var ctrls = angular.module('MyModule',[]);
ctrls.controller('FooCtrl', ['$scope', '$location','service',
  function( $scope,$location,service)
  {
     $scope.Bars = service.Bars;
     $scope.Baz = service.Baz;
  }

var app = angular.module('MyModule.Services',['ngResource']);
app.service('service', ['$resource', function($resource)
{
  var proxy = $resource(
       'http://server/subsystem/api/Foo/:component',
        {},
        {
           Bars: {method:'GET',isArray:false,url: 'http://server/subsystem/api/Foo/Bars'
          ,Baz: {method:'GET',isArray:false,rul: 'http://server/subsystem/api/Foo/Baz'
        }
  return proxy;
}]);
```

blah blah blah, ng-repeat in my view bound to "bar in Bars" = data to screen.

So now, I go into my controller to implement my interval, and I can get the interval working but the promise does not resolve.

The changes inside the controller (note that I added $interval and $document to my dependency list:

```
var stop;
$scope.Bars = {};
$scope.Baz = service.Baz; //Note that angular resolves this promise automatically.
$scope.pollService = function(){
   if(angular.isDefined(stop))return;
   stop = $interval(function(){
     if(service){
        $scope.Bars = service.Bars;
     }
   },1000);
};
$scope.stopPolling = function(){
   if(angular.isDefined(stop)){
     $interval.cancel(stop);
     stop = undefined;
   }
};
$scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
   $scope.stopPolling();
});
$document.ready(function(){
   $scope.pollService(); //when I attempt to execute my .then() on pollService(), I get "cannot 
                         //call then on undefined"
});
```

### Edit

Note that the problem I am having is that binding $scope.Bars directly to service.Bars triggers angular's automatic promise resolution but introducing the $interval call does not seem to be.  Inspecting $scope.Bars in Chrome Dev Tools indicates that it is an unresolved promise.

I updated my sample code to match what I currently have in my debugger.  I have several properties defined on my resource, and I included one that I named 'Baz'.  If I assign $scope.Baz = service.Baz directly within my controller, the view binds to it when angular resolves the promise but the one on the interval never does.

Comment: error in transcribing my code. I'll clean it up

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning the `promise` from `$scope.pollService`. Just add `return stop;` at the end of your function. Also note that the way your API is written, your function will still return `undefined`  if `stop` is defined.

Therefore, it should probably look like:

```
$scope.pollService = function(){
   if(!angular.isDefined(stop)) {
       stop = $interval(function() {
         if(service){
            $scope.Bars = service.Bars;
         }
       }, 1000);
  }

  return stop;
};
```

`stop` is also not a very good descriptive name...

EDIT:

From my understanding after reading the docs, you should be invoking the action method on the service like `$scope.Bars = service.Bars();`. This will return an object that will eventually get populated with data once the promise is resolved. However, I think you also need to be careful here, because if the interval fires faster than the promise resolving rate you might run into issues. I think that you would be better off using `$timeout`.

Comment: It's lifted straight from the angular documentation for $interval. I'm just trying to get it functioning at the moment.  
Also, returning "stop" does not resolve the promise; I wish that was it :P

Comment: @K.AlanBates `$interval` does return a promise as the docs states. If you correctly return from `$scope.pollService`, then you should be able to do `$scope.pollService().then(...)`. If that doesn't work there's another issue in your code somewhere.

Comment: I am returning stop from `$scope.pollService` and `$scope.pollService().then(function...)` never fires. I have a break point set in the success callback and one in the error callback. I already knew that `$interval` returned a promise. The question now(as it always was) is why binding `$scope.Bars` directly to `service.Bars` triggers Angular's automatic promise resolution but introducing an interval does not. If I unwrap the service calls from the interval and just set `$scope.Bars = service.Bars`, my bound controls in my view display data from service.Bars.

Comment: @K.AlanBates Well, that's not what your question stated. You were stating that you were getting `cannot call then on undefined`. Anyway, have you checked if the callback function itself was getting invoked? Rather than setting break points, put `debugger;` statements in your code where you want it to break, it's more trustable.

Comment: The comment about pollService.then inside my code block was an aside. I had *tried* to call pollService.then inside $document.ready and it was not resolving.  Adding return stop resolved that (fairly minor) issue, but the problem is that returning Bars from service through an $interval is not triggering angular's automatic promise resolution

Comment: I don't really want to have to manually resolve the promise.  I want to bind to it and let angular handle the resolution and data binding. Any ideas on why $interval would/could be getting in the way?

Comment: Is the `if(service){` statement entered?

Comment: yeah.  I've got a breakpoint set on the assignment of `$scope.Bars = service.Bars` and it executes, and it assigns the promise to $scope.Bars, and it repeats the assignment on its interval, but the view is never bound to the result of the promise.  Eliminating the interval and binding `$scope.Bars` directly to `service.Bars` in the controller assigns the promise to $scope.Bars and when the call comes back, the view displays my resultant data.

Comment: @K.AlanBates Are you sure that you shouldn't be doing `$scope.Bars = service.Bars();`?

Comment: ...lemme try that. But, in my controller, I have `$scope.Baz = service.Baz` and angular resolves that promise without any issue.
...ok.  I changed to `$scope.Bars = service.Bars();` inside of my interval function and it jumped into wrappedProgressBack (line 11538 of angular.js).

Comment: @K.AlanBates Unfortunately, I only used Angular once and never touched `$resource`, so my experience and knowledge falls short on this one. From my understanding, invoking the custom action method yields an object that will later be populated once the promise resolves and there should be a digest cycle after every `$interval`, but I am not sure what's happening here. Try to make your interval longer to make sure that the callback isin't getting called again before the promise gets resolved.

Comment: The poll interval may be an issue but I don't think it's the issue I'm running into right now.  These calls return in about a second and a half. I set the interval to 6s and when the interval function is called, the data that my view is bound to gets wiped and nothing ever gets returned.  Thanks for your help.  I'm going to need to get going; hopefully I'll come in first thing tomorrow and someone will have set me straight lol

Comment: I swear to Gawd, I must not have flushed my browser cache when I tried assigning `$scope.Bars = service.Bars();`  The promise gets resolved...but now I have another issue that I'll bring up separately.

If you modify to mention that $scope.Bars has to be assigned to service.Bars(), I'll accept your answer